# How to implement both google and Azure SSO in .NET Core 6.0

Tags: authentication, .net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I am getting this error while trying to authenticate using google.
Google SSO and Azure SSO is working independently but I need both of this

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: the authentication handler registered for scheme 'OpenIdConnect' is 'OpenIdConnectHandler' which cannot be used for SignInAsync. The registered sign-in schemes are: Cookies.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.SignInAsync(HttpContext context, string scheme, ClaimsPrincipal principal, AuthenticationProperties properties)

My code:

```
public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Your API", Version = "v1" });
    });

    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())

        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")

        .AddEnvironmentVariables()

        .Build();

    // Configure Azure AD authentication
    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "user.read" })
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

    // Configure Google authentication
    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
        });

    services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

    services.AddAuthorization();
    services.AddTransient<IPolicyService, PolicyService>();
    services.AddTransient<IRedisService, RedisService>();
}
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue, have you resolved this?